# Convert a string to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I have a string as below

```
 gmr='rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1,rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales'
```

If you see clearly its kind of 2 dictionaries 
 rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1
and 
 rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales

I want to convert them to as below

```
 [
  {'rule': 'sum', 'attribute': 'sales', 'name': 'sum_sales'},
    {'rule': 'unique', 'attribute': 'geo', 'name': 'uniq1'}
 ]
```

Kindly help

I tried

```
gmr='rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1,rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales'
 dlist=[]
 at_rule_gm=(x.split(':') for x in gmr.split(','))
 dict(at_rule_gm)
```

but here I get only the last dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with sample of OP:

```
>>> gmr='rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1,rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales'
```

Make an empty list first.

```
>>> dlist = [ ]
```

Loop with `entry` over list, yielded by `gmr.split(',')`,

Store `entry.split(':')` into `pair`,

Check whether first value in `pair` (the key) is `'rule'`

If so, append a new empty dictionary to `dlist`

Store pair into last entry of `dlist`:

```
>>> for entry in gmr.split(','):
    pair = entry.split(':')
    if pair[0] == 'rule':
        dlist.append({ })
    dlist[-1][pair[0]] = pair[1]
```

Print result:

```
>>> print(dlist)
[{'name': 'unq1', 'attribute': 'geo', 'rule': 'unique'},
   {'name': 'sum_sales', 'attribute': 'sales', 'rule': 'sum'}]
```

Looks like what OP intended to get.

Answer (score 1):

gmr='rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1,rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales'
split_str = gmr.split(',')
dlist = []

for num in range(0, len(split_str),3):

```
temp_dict = {}
temp1 = split_str[num]
temp2 = split_str[num+1]
temp3 = split_str[num+2]
key,value = temp1.split(':')
temp_dict.update({key:value})
key,value = temp2.split(':')
temp_dict.update({key:value})
key,value = temp3.split(':')
temp_dict.update({key:value})
dlist.append(temp_dict)
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` always gives a single dictionary, not a `list` of dictionaries. For the latter, you can use a list comprehension after first splitting by `'rule:'`:

```
gmr = 'rule:unique,attribute:geo,name:unq1,rule:sum,attribute:sales,name:sum_sales'

items = (f'rule:{x}' for x in filter(None, gmr.split('rule:')))
res = [dict(x.split(':') for x in item.split(',') if x) for item in items]

print(res)

# [{'attribute': 'geo', 'name': 'unq1', 'rule': 'unique'},
#  {'attribute': 'sales', 'name': 'sum_sales', 'rule': 'sum'}]
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-367-dcc148ac40d3> in <module>()
      1 items = (f'rule:{x}' for x in filter(None, gmr.split('rule:')))
----> 2 res = [dict(x.split(':') for x in item.split(',') if x) for item in items]

<ipython-input-367-dcc148ac40d3> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 items = (f'rule:{x}' for x in filter(None, gmr.split('rule:')))
----> 2 res = [dict(x.split(':') for x in item.split(',') if x) for item in items]

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @KumarP, Can't replicate, the example I give works fine and is identical to your input.

Comment: @KumarP, It's probably because you've defined a variable `dict` earlier. Don't do this. Use `d_`, `dict_`, `dct`, or something else.